# How can I find nodes which have an attribute equals to one of attributes parental node?

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes

i am a very newbie in XML and XPath world and I hope you can resolve some of my doubts.
Here's a short part of the XML file.

```
<country name="Mexico" population="95772464" area="1972550">
<city>
<name>Nezahualcoyotl</name>
<population>1255456</population>
</city>
<city>
<name>Mexico</name>
<population>9815795</population>
</city>
</country>
```

I have to find cities which have the same name of their country. 
How can i resolve this? thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
//country/city[name=../@name]
```

Above xpath return list of `<city>` nodes matching the *predicate* (the expression within `[]`). The predicate itself compares equality of child node `<name>` value with the parent node's `name` attribute value

- `name` : get child node `<name>`
- `../@name` : get parent node then get its `name` attribute